# Simple Media query rules change on page refresh

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float, media-queries

I have a strange problem. Media query rules in my CSS trigger at a certain widths like they are supposed to, however if I already resized the browser window to that smaller width, then expand the browser window beyond it something odd happens. Things appear normal until I refresh the page. The layout changes in an unexpected way only on page refresh. The goal of course is for the media queries to behave normally as in a page refresh shouldn't change any rules.

I tried to recreate the problem using the bare bones:

```js
//CSS media queries added to style tag here to prevent scrolling in other code blocks
var style = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[ 0 ];

style.innerHTML += 
'                                                                           \
  @media( max-width: 550px ) {                                              \
    body {                                                                  \
      background-color: #ddd;                                               \
      transition: 1s;                                                       \
    }                                                                       \
    main {                                                                  \
      height: auto;                                                         \
      text-align: center;                                                   \
    }                                                                       \
    .circle, .about-container {                                             \
      float: none;                                                          \
    }                                                                       \
    .circle {                                                               \
      display: inline-block;                                                \
      transform: translateY( 0 );                                           \
    }                                                                       \
    .about-container {                                                      \
      margin: 0 auto;                                                       \
      text-align: left;                                                     \
    }                                                                       \
  }                                                                         \
  @media( min-width: 551px ) {                                              \
    .circle {                                                               \
      transform: translateY( 0 );                                           \
    }                                                                       \
  }                                                                         \
';
```

```css
/* ///////////////// ELEMENTS IN ORDER THEY APPEAR IN HTML ///////////////// */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 11rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  top: calc( 50% - 10px );
}

.about-container {
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
}

body button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
  
    /* ///////////// BASIC STYLES TO MAKE THIS SNIPPET LOOK BETTER ///////////// */
    @import url('https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css');
    
    .clearfix:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      clear: both;
    }
    .vertically-center {
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY( -50% );
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <main class="clearfix">
    <div class="circle vertically-center"></div>
    <div class="about-container">
      <h3>About</h3>
      <p>
        This problem is wierd. When <strong>snippet is made full screen</strong> 
        and browser width is shrunk to less than <strong>550px</strong> <em>
        ( You will know you're at 550px because the background will darken )</em> 
        the layout changes - as expected. However when window is expanded beyond 
        550px again and <strong>Reload Frame</strong> is clicked the layout 
        unexpectedly updates itself. <br><br>What's going on?
      </p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <button onclick="location.reload()">Reload Frame</button>
</body>
```

Though weird I have a feeling this has a simple solution, I hope?

**Edit:** I'm seeing these results on the chrome browser. Will upload a GIF that demonstrates what I see below.

[image]

Comment: Did you 
1) Go full page
2) shrink the width until the background darkens.
3) expand the width until the background is white.  4) Click the button?

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: Chrome. I'm uploading a gif that demonstrates What I see.

Comment: @MrLister my problem isn't a JavaScript one. It's the CSS media queries firing on refresh. The javaScript here is only for this demo.

Comment: @L.S Please see update with gif showing my issue.

Comment: @MrLister When I remove all of the JavaScript and just add all the CSS rules to the `style` tag in the HTML this problem still persists. On my actual site I'm working on there is no javaScript and this problem arose. What is here is a very basic version of the full site.

Comment: OK, sorry, I wasn't looking carefully. I see what goes wrong now, but the problem occurs even before the refresh: what actually happens is that the black circle moves upwards when the window is made narrower, and then it doesn't move back down when you make the window wider again. And this happens only in Chrome, not in Firefox or IE11.

Comment: @MrLister I think the black circle moves up because I change its `transformY` position. This is normal behavior as far as I'm concerned. What's strange is the refresh moving it again.

Comment: No. What strange is that making the window wider again doesn't move it back down!

Comment: Yeah..It's like a value in the CSS changes but *forgets* to change back.

Comment: By adding `margin-top:11%` to `.vertically-center` div then the circle comes back to it's original state after resizing the window back..! :D

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai Thanks! Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to previous answers for pointing out that this was a browser quirk in chrome. However none of the solutions are as simple as they could be. I found the key problem was `display: inline-block` under the `@media( max-width: 550px )` media query. I removed that, changed it to `display: block` and added `margin: 0 auto` to recenter the circle being that it's no longer affected by the `text-align: center` rule on it's parent. This solves the problem in the simplest way for me. Here is the snippet:

```js
//CSS media queries added to style tag here to prevent scrolling in other code blocks
var style = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[ 0 ];

style.innerHTML += 
'                                                                           \
  @media( max-width: 550px ) {                                              \
    body {                                                                  \
      background-color: #ddd;                                               \
      transition: 1s;                                                       \
    }                                                                       \
    main {                                                                  \
      height: auto;                                                         \
      text-align: center;                                                   \
    }                                                                       \
    .circle, .about-container {                                             \
      float: none;                                                          \
    }                                                                       \
    .circle {                                                               \
      display: block; /* changed display: inline-block to display: block */ \
      margin: 0 auto; /* added this line to recenter the circle */          \
      transform: translateY( 0 );                                           \
    }                                                                       \
    .about-container {                                                      \
      margin: 0 auto;                                                       \
      text-align: left;                                                     \
    }                                                                       \
  }                                                                         \
  @media( min-width: 551px ) {                                              \
    .circle {                                                               \
      transform: translateY( 0 );                                           \
    }                                                                       \
  }                                                                         \
';
```

```css
/* ///////////////// ELEMENTS IN ORDER THEY APPEAR IN HTML ///////////////// */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 11rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  top: calc( 50% - 10px );
}

.about-container {
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
}

body button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
  
    /* ///////////// BASIC STYLES TO MAKE THIS SNIPPET LOOK BETTER ///////////// */
    @import url('https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css');
    
    .clearfix:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      clear: both;
    }
    .vertically-center {
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY( -50% );
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <main class="clearfix">
    <div class="circle vertically-center"></div>
    <div class="about-container">
      <h3>About</h3>
      <p>
        This problem is wierd. When <strong>snippet is made full screen</strong> 
        and browser width is shrunk to less than <strong>550px</strong> <em>
        ( You will know you're at 550px because the background will darken )</em> 
        the layout changes - as expected. However when window is expanded beyond 
        550px again and <strong>Reload Frame</strong> is clicked the layout 
        unexpectedly updates itself. <br><br>What's going on?
      </p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <button onclick="location.reload()">Reload Frame</button>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Chrome has a problem with elements that are floated, positioned and translated at the same time. Again, this is a flaw in Chrome, not in your code.
One way out of this is to use no positioning, only translation to move the circle.

```js
//CSS media queries added to style tag here to prevent scrolling in other code blocks

var style = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[ 0 ];

style.innerHTML += 
'                                                                           \
  @media( max-width: 550px ) {                                              \
    body {                                                                  \
      background-color: #ddd;                                               \
    }                                                                       \
    main {                                                                  \
      height: auto;                                                         \
      text-align: center;                                                   \
    }                                                                       \
    .circle, .about-container {                                             \
      float: none;                                                          \
    }                                                                       \
    .circle {                                                               \
      display: inline-block;                                                \
      transform: translateY(-40%); /* changed a bit to compensate */        \
    }                                                                       \
    .about-container {                                                      \
      margin: 0 auto;                                                       \
      text-align: left;                                                     \
    }                                                                       \
  }                                                                         \
';
```

```css
/* ///////////////// ELEMENTS IN ORDER THEY APPEAR IN HTML ///////////////// */

body {
  transition: 0.25s;
}

main {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 11rem;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.circle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}
/* this was moved here */
.vertically-center {
  transform: translateY(40%);
}

.about-container {
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
}

body button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    /* ///////////// BASIC STYLES TO MAKE THIS SNIPPET LOOK BETTER ///////////// */
    @import url('https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css');
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .clearfix:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      clear: both;
    }
    /* moved the .vertically-center bit to before the media query */
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <main class="clearfix">
    <div class="circle vertically-center"></div>
    <div class="about-container">
      <h3>About</h3>
      <p>
        This problem is pretty wierd. When you
        <strong>make this snippet full screen</strong> and try shrinking the browser
        width to less than <strong>550px</strong> <em>( You will know you're at 550px
        because the background will darken )</em> the layout changes - Which is 
        expected. However when you expand the window beyond 550px again and click 
        <strong>Reload Frame</strong> the current layout unexpectedly updates
        itself. <br><br>What's going on?
      </p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <button onclick="location.reload()">Reload Frame</button>
</body>
```

But as others have shown, there are more solutions. Take your pick!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this is a browser quirk in Chrome. I initially didn't think to even check for that. I've done more tests and it seems like the `transform` property has no effect on bringing about this problem. It's the positioned element and the float. Remove either of them and problem fixed. I like your solution. Doing more testing.

Comment: I found a simpler solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution :** The simple solution is to add `margin-top:11%` to `div.vertically-center` then the circle comes back to it's original state after resizing the window back..! :D

And fixing a CSS issue has lots of ways to be fixed it can even be fixed with just adding some html elements along with css code or just by changing the current css and without adding any elements.So it's up to you which one to follow then.

**BETTER WAY TO USE IT :**
Since I checked that the `margin-top:11%` messes up with Firefox style so you can use following two ways to just apply it to Chrome only as :

**1) Chrome JavaScript Solution :**

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Chrome/") != -1) {
document.getElementById("vertically-center").style.marginTop = "11%";
}
```

**2) Chrome CSS Solution :**

```
/* Chrome 29+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
  and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
   .vertically-center { margin-top:11%; }
}

/* Chrome 22-28 */
@media screen and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  .selector {-chrome-:only(; 
     property:value;
  );} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update code 
try this run code

```
<div class="circlemain">
   <div class="circle vertically-center"></div>
</div>

   .circlemain {
        top: 50%;
        position: relative;
    }

@media( max-width: 550px ) {  
    .vertically-center {
     position: relative;
     transform: translateY( 0% ) !important;
     top: 50%;
 }
```

```js
//CSS media queries added to style tag here to prevent scrolling in other code blocks

    var style = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[ 0 ];

    style.innerHTML += 
    '                                                                           \
      @media( max-width: 550px ) {                                              \
        body {                                                                  \
          background-color: #ddd;                                               \
        }                                                                       \
        main {                                                                  \
          height: auto;                                                         \
          text-align: center;                                                   \
        }                                                                       \
        .circle, .about-container {                                             \
          float: none;                                                          \
        }                                                                       \
        .circle {                                                               \
          display: inline-block;                                                \
          transform: translateY( 0 );                                           \
        }                                                                       \
        .about-container {                                                      \
          margin: 0 auto;                                                       \
          text-align: left;                                                     \
        }                                                                       \
      }                                                                         \
      @media( min-width: 551px ) {                                              \
        .circle {                                                               \
          transform: translateY( 0 );                                           \
        }                                                                       \
      }                                                                         \
    ';
```

```css
/* ///////////////// ELEMENTS IN ORDER THEY APPEAR IN HTML ///////////////// */

    main {
      max-width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 11rem;
      padding-top: 10px;
      font-size: 0.8rem;
      text-align: left;
    }
.circlemain {
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
    .circle {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: #444;
      border-radius: 50%;
      float: left;
      top: calc( 50% - 10px );
    }

    .about-container {
      width: 75%;
      float: right;
    }

    body button {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    @media( max-width: 550px ) {  
    .vertically-center {
        position: relative;
        transform: translateY( 0% ) !important;
        top: 50%;
    }
    
     }
```

```html
<head>
      <style>
        /* ///////////// BASIC STYLES TO MAKE THIS SNIPPET LOOK BETTER ///////////// */
        @import url('https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css');
        * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .clearfix:after {
          content: "";
          display: block;
          clear: both;
        }
        .vertically-center {
          position: relative;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translateY( -50% );
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <main class="clearfix">
        <div class="circlemain">
        <div class="circle vertically-center"></div>
</div>
        <div class="about-container">
          <h3>About</h3>
          <p>
            This problem is pretty wierd. When you
            <strong>make this snippet full screen</strong> and try shrinking the browser
            width to less than <strong>550px</strong> <em>( You will know you're at 550px
            because the background will darken )</em> the layout changes - Which is 
            expected. However when you expand the window beyond 550px again and click 
            <strong>Reload Frame</strong> the current layout unexpectedly updates
            itself. <br><br>What's going on?
          </p>
        </div>
      </main>
      <button onclick="location.reload()">Reload Frame</button>
    </body>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works, what the problem was with the OP's code and how this fixes the problem? By the way, the behaviour of this snippet is different than the OP's in narrow windows.